# os unable to load image pygame.error: Couldn't open imgs\pipe.png

Tags: python, pygame

source code : https://github.com/techwithtim/NEAT-Flappy-Bird  line 28 - 31  (tech with tims flappy bird deep learning ai)

```
pipe_img = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","pipe.png")).convert_alpha())
bg_img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","bg.png")).convert_alpha(), (600, 900))
bird_images = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","bird" + str(x) + ".png"))) for x in range(1,4)]
base_img = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","base.png")).convert_alpha())
```

i at first thought it was a local problem but after fiddling with python and uninstalling installing and reinstalling it i can conclude it is almost certainly not that.

here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/osty2/Documents/programing_projects/NEAT-Flappy-Bird/flappy_bird.py", line 28, in <module>
    pipe_img = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","pipe.png")).convert_alpha())
pygame.error: Couldn't open imgs\pipe.png
PS C:\Users\osty2\Documents\programing_projects>
```

its an os error but everything that i've tried doesn't work.everything in the requirements folder is installed, everything is run on 3.8.6 and was also tested on 3.7.2, 3.7.9 and 3.9.0.

[issue submitted in github](https://github.com/techwithtim/NEAT-Flappy-Bird/issues/20)

[issue submitted to reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/j9jvz8/os_unable_to_load_image_pygmeerror_couldnt_open/)

[image: picture of an images folder thats there]

Comment: sorry to everyone for originally puting it as a question about deep learning, that was just the subject of the code but not the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with your version of python and it's not an issue with the repo. From what I can tell, you are trying to run the app from `C:\Users\osty2\Documents\programing_projects`, which has no `imgs` folder.

Navigate to `C:\Users\osty2\Documents\programing_projects\NEAT-flappy-bird` and then run it. The application will then be able to see the `imgs` folder.

Comment: i edited it to show a picture of the img folder still being there. also i do not believe that its a problem with the repo as other people are having it work fine.

Comment: nevermind you were right i didn't read what you said properly, thank you.